# ADB command to list only the number of running apps on the device

Tags: android, adb

What is the `adb` command to list only the number of running apps on the device? This should include both `/system/app` and `/data/app`.

---

These are my system app example, I want to know which ones are running?

```
shell@m0:/ $ ls -ll /system/app/                                               
-rw-r--r-- root     root       355694 2014-04-04 17:19 AccuweatherDaemon.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       144896 2014-04-04 17:19 AccuweatherDaemon.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      5307122 2014-04-04 17:17 AccuweatherWidget.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       156600 2014-04-04 17:18 AccuweatherWidget.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      4683591 2014-04-04 17:17 AccuweatherWidget_Main.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       574776 2014-04-04 17:19 AccuweatherWidget_Main.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       159734 2014-04-04 17:17 AllShareCastPlayer.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        46656 2014-04-04 17:19 AllShareCastPlayer.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       363856 2008-08-01 22:00 AllshareControlShare.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        40195 2008-08-01 22:00 AllshareFileShare.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       122968 2014-04-04 17:18 AllshareFileShare.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       320032 2014-04-04 17:19 AllshareFileShareClient.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       159336 2014-04-04 17:19 AllshareFileShareClient.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       716743 2014-04-04 17:19 AllshareFileShareServer.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       129344 2014-04-04 17:19 AllshareFileShareServer.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       569249 2014-04-04 17:19 AllshareMediaServer.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       564192 2014-04-04 17:19 AllshareMediaServer.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       952079 2008-08-01 22:00 AllshareMediaShare.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       389288 2008-08-01 22:00 AllshareMediaShare.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       140169 2014-04-04 17:18 AnalogClockSimple.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        11200 2014-04-04 17:18 AnalogClockSimple.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1359282 2014-04-04 17:18 AnalogClockUnique.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        11376 2014-04-04 17:18 AnalogClockUnique.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        16040 2014-04-04 17:18 ApplicationsProvider.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        25184 2014-04-04 17:18 ApplicationsProvider.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root         4496 2014-04-04 17:18 BCService.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        34688 2014-04-04 17:18 BCService.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        96025 2014-04-04 17:18 BackupRestoreConfirmation.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        10056 2014-04-04 17:18 BackupRestoreConfirmation.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root         4270 2014-04-04 17:18 BadgeProvider.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root         9848 2014-04-04 17:18 BadgeProvider.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       531130 2008-08-01 22:00 BandService.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        33331 2008-08-01 22:00 BasicDreams.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        16888 2008-08-01 22:00 BasicDreams.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       203950 2008-08-01 22:00 BestFace.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       753109 2014-04-04 17:19 Bluetooth.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1356440 2014-04-04 17:20 Bluetooth.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        13550 2014-04-04 17:18 BluetoothTest.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        46032 2014-04-04 17:18 BluetoothTest.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      5310029 2014-04-04 17:18 Books.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        26759 2014-04-04 17:18 CSC.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       424496 2014-04-04 17:19 CSC.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        17653 2014-04-04 17:18 CapabilityManagerService.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       156714 2014-04-04 17:19 CertInstaller.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        46960 2014-04-04 17:18 CertInstaller.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root     15217364 2014-04-04 17:19 ChatON_MARKET.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1006251 2014-04-04 17:19 ChocoEUKor.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       215783 2014-04-04 17:18 ChromeBookmarksSyncAdapter.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      9504796 2014-04-04 17:20 ChromeWithBrowser.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        16421 2014-04-04 17:18 ClipboardSaveService.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        24824 2014-04-04 17:18 ClipboardSaveService.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      7632345 2014-04-04 17:17 ClockPackage.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1280176 2014-04-04 17:19 ClockPackage.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       526798 2008-08-01 22:00 CloudAgent.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       858236 2008-08-01 22:00 ConfigUpdater.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        23899 2014-04-04 17:18 ContextProvider.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       648280 2014-04-04 17:19 ContextProvider.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1174555 2008-08-01 22:00 CoolEUKor.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        20741 2014-04-04 17:18 DSMForwarding.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        12232 2014-04-04 17:18 DSMForwarding.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       929810 2014-04-04 17:18 DSMLawmo.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       136224 2014-04-04 17:18 DSMLawmo.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       455601 2014-04-04 17:18 DeepSea.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       139728 2014-04-04 17:18 DeepSea.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root         8235 2014-04-04 17:18 DefaultContainerService.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        22984 2014-04-04 17:18 DefaultContainerService.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        98903 2014-04-04 17:18 DigitalClock.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        22304 2014-04-04 17:18 DigitalClock.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       349870 2014-04-04 17:19 DigitalClock21.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        19752 2014-04-04 17:18 DigitalClock21.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       451194 2014-04-04 17:19 DirectConnect.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       103960 2014-04-04 17:18 DirectConnect.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       589579 2014-04-04 17:19 DirectShareManager.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       162968 2014-04-04 17:18 DirectShareManager.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       203008 2014-04-04 17:19 Divx.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        12768 2014-04-04 17:18 Divx.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        22703 2014-04-04 17:18 DrmProvider.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        13432 2014-04-04 17:18 DrmProvider.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       243470 2008-08-01 22:00 DroidSansSherifItalic.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      6396835 2014-04-04 17:21 Dropbox.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1186366 2014-04-04 17:20 DropboxOOBE.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      3239622 2014-04-04 17:19 DualClockAnalog.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       104064 2014-04-04 17:18 DualClockAnalog.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1270752 2014-04-04 17:18 DualClockDigital.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        75992 2014-04-04 17:18 DualClockDigital.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1531476 2014-04-04 17:19 DualClockDigital42.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       128240 2014-04-04 17:18 DualClockDigital42.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       240260 2008-08-01 22:00 ELMAgent.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       273120 2008-08-01 22:00 ELMAgent.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root         3470 2008-08-01 22:00 EdmSimPinService.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root         8576 2008-08-01 22:00 EdmSimPinService.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root         3417 2014-04-04 17:18 EdmSysScopeService.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root         4312 2014-04-04 17:18 EdmSysScopeService.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root         3471 2014-04-04 17:18 EdmVpnServices.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       125072 2014-04-04 17:18 EdmVpnServices.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        14359 2014-04-04 17:18 EnterprisePermissions.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        19181 2014-04-04 17:18 FFFFFFFF000000000000000000000001.drbin
-rw-r--r-- root     root        24488 2014-04-04 17:18 FWUpgrade.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        19000 2014-04-04 17:18 FWUpgrade.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1482195 2014-04-04 17:19 FaceLock.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      2996235 2014-04-04 17:19 FactoryTest.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      2247357 2014-04-04 17:20 FlashBarService.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       411720 2014-04-04 17:19 FlashBarService.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      4125021 2013-08-21 16:32 Flipboard.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      6408262 2014-04-04 17:18 FmRadio.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       421800 2014-04-04 17:19 FmRadio.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        59685 2014-04-04 17:18 FmmDM.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       863952 2014-04-04 17:18 FmmDM.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        25802 2014-04-04 17:18 FmmDS.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       301688 2014-04-04 17:18 FmmDS.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       805198 2014-04-04 17:19 FotaClient.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       207248 2014-04-04 17:19 FotaClient.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root         3771 2008-08-01 22:00 FusedLocation.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        12960 2008-08-01 22:00 FusedLocation.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      6656791 2014-04-04 17:17 GMS_Maps.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      6114804 2014-04-04 17:21 GameHub_2.0_ICS_oldkey.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       975588 2008-08-01 22:00 GearManagerStub.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      4223047 2014-04-04 17:19 Gmail2.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      7468035 2014-04-04 17:21 GmsCore.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       122482 2014-04-04 17:18 GoogleBackupTransport.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       497304 2014-04-04 17:19 GoogleCalendarSyncAdapter.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       199776 2014-04-04 17:18 GoogleContactsSyncAdapter.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root     10095883 2008-08-01 22:00 GoogleDrive.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       285097 2014-04-04 17:18 GoogleFeedback.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      4917245 2014-04-04 17:19 GoogleLoginService.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       126899 2014-04-04 17:18 GooglePartnerSetup.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        42236 2014-04-04 17:18 GoogleSearchWidget.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root         3736 2014-04-04 17:18 GoogleSearchWidget.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1612126 2014-04-04 17:18 GoogleServicesFramework.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      5598284 2014-04-04 17:18 GoogleTTS.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      3733902 2014-04-04 17:20 GroupPlay_25_stub.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      8370864 2008-08-01 22:00 Hangouts.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      2905455 2014-04-04 17:18 Hearingdro_JU.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      5504424 2014-04-04 17:20 HelpHub.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       162048 2014-04-04 17:19 HelpHub.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       327934 2013-08-21 16:32 INDI_Server.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        49327 2014-04-04 17:18 InputDevices.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root         2008 2014-04-04 17:18 InputDevices.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1174193 2014-04-04 17:19 JobManager.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       210768 2014-04-04 17:19 JobManager.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        44447 2014-04-04 17:18 KeyChain.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        31448 2014-04-04 17:18 KeyChain.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root         3876 2008-08-01 22:00 KeyguardBackupRestore.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       202240 2008-08-01 22:00 KeyguardBackupRestore.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       782878 2014-04-04 17:18 KeyguardWidget.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        64456 2014-04-04 17:19 KeyguardWidget.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      2089107 2014-04-04 17:18 Keystring_DFT.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       494469 2014-04-04 17:19 Keystring_factory.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        39994 2014-04-04 17:18 Keystring_misc.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        24368 2014-04-04 17:18 Kies.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        66848 2014-04-04 17:18 Kies.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      4667994 2014-04-04 17:19 Lcdtest.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root         5260 2014-04-04 17:18 LogsProvider.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       115280 2014-04-04 17:19 LogsProvider.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       276716 2014-04-04 17:18 LuminousDots.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       158200 2014-04-04 17:18 LuminousDots.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        42387 2014-04-04 17:19 MDMApp.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        10888 2014-04-04 17:18 MDMApp.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1828444 2008-08-01 22:00 MMAppFramework.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       159736 2008-08-01 22:00 MMAppFramework.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       356930 2014-04-04 17:19 MediaUploader.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       774695 2014-04-04 17:19 MobilePrint.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1855120 2014-04-04 17:19 MobilePrint.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        22269 2014-04-04 17:18 MobileTrackerEngineTwo.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        17520 2014-04-04 17:18 MobileTrackerEngineTwo.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        68660 2014-04-04 17:18 MoreServices.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root         8344 2014-04-04 17:18 MoreServices.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       449782 2014-04-04 17:18 MtpApplication.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        70032 2014-04-04 17:18 MtpApplication.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      7851320 2014-04-04 17:20 Music2.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        50855 2014-04-04 17:18 MusicFX.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        87184 2014-04-04 17:18 MusicFX.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        25044 2008-08-01 22:00 MusicHubAUStub_V6.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      4469127 2008-08-01 22:00 MusicHub_31.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      6326878 2008-08-01 22:00 MusicLiveShare2.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       451048 2008-08-01 22:00 MusicLiveShare2.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      4581964 2014-04-04 17:17 MusicPlayerWT.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1334456 2014-04-04 17:19 MusicPlayerWT.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root     14909268 2008-08-01 22:00 Navigator_Select_Samsung_PAC_v4.7.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       341417 2014-04-04 17:18 NetworkLocation.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      6924010 2008-08-01 22:00 Newsstand.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       332342 2014-04-04 17:19 Nfc.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       406656 2014-04-04 17:19 Nfc.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        21240 2014-04-04 17:18 NfcTest.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        40560 2014-04-04 17:18 NfcTest.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        98640 2014-04-04 17:18 NoiseField.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        26592 2014-04-04 17:18 NoiseField.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       223463 2008-08-01 22:00 NotificationWidget.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        15872 2008-08-01 22:00 NotificationWidget.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       304383 2014-04-04 17:19 OmaCP.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       240128 2014-04-04 17:18 OmaCP.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        23347 2014-04-04 17:18 OmaDrmPopup.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root         7464 2014-04-04 17:18 OmaDrmPopup.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        53963 2014-04-04 17:18 PCWClientS.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       377217 2014-04-04 17:19 PackageInstaller.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       597376 2014-04-04 17:19 PackageInstaller.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       148152 2008-08-01 22:00 PageBuddyNotiSvc.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        31576 2008-08-01 22:00 PageBuddyNotiSvc.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      4506220 2014-04-04 17:19 PanningTryActually.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        30840 2014-04-04 17:18 PanningTryActually.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      7817513 2014-04-04 17:17 PaperArtist.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root         3418 2014-04-04 17:18 PartnerBookmarksProvider.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        10720 2014-04-04 17:18 PartnerBookmarksProvider.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       103088 2014-04-04 17:19 PhaseBeam.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        23360 2014-04-04 17:18 PhaseBeam.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        57578 2014-04-04 17:18 PhoneErrService.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        24056 2014-04-04 17:18 PhoneErrService.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      6038575 2014-04-04 17:18 Phonesky.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       446028 2014-04-04 17:17 PhotoTable.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        84296 2008-08-01 22:00 PhotoTable.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      2148387 2014-04-04 17:18 PhotoWall.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       184896 2014-04-04 17:18 PhotoWall.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      6308745 2014-04-04 17:21 PickUpTutorial.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       212816 2014-04-04 17:18 PickUpTutorial.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      2053143 2008-08-01 22:00 PlayGames.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root     18247774 2014-04-04 17:22 PlusOne.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      4275975 2014-04-04 17:18 PolarisViewer.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       402436 2014-04-04 17:19 PopupuiReceiver.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        34248 2014-04-04 17:18 PopupuiReceiver.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root         9340 2014-04-04 17:18 Preconfig.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        23816 2014-04-04 17:18 Preconfig.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        40965 2014-04-04 17:18 PreloadInstaller.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        55888 2014-04-04 17:19 PreloadInstaller.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       146404 2008-08-01 22:00 RootPA.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        70960 2014-04-04 17:17 RootPA.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1045001 2014-04-04 17:19 RoseEUKor.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root     22291550 2008-08-01 22:00 S-Voice_Android_phone_H.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1054629 2008-08-01 22:00 SCONE_Android_ProxyService.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       251337 2008-08-01 22:00 SCParser.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root     17010575 2014-04-04 17:20 SMemo.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      4381944 2014-04-04 17:19 SMemo.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      6486403 2014-04-04 17:18 SMemoProvider.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        90792 2014-04-04 17:18 SMemoProvider.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1010989 2014-04-04 17:19 SNS.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       592895 2014-04-04 17:19 SPPPushClient_Prod.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1964969 2014-04-04 17:17 SPlannerAppWidget.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       250896 2014-04-04 17:18 SPlannerAppWidget.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      4972590 2008-08-01 22:00 SSuggest_J_DeviceOnly.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root     15751167 2014-04-04 17:22 SamsungApps.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        92527 2014-04-04 17:18 SamsungAppsUNA3.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      4251529 2014-04-04 17:20 SamsungCamera.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1709128 2014-04-04 17:19 SamsungCamera.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      7349156 2014-04-04 17:20 SamsungIME.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      4619648 2014-04-04 17:20 SamsungIME.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1037602 2008-08-01 22:00 SamsungLink18_stub.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       441863 2014-04-04 17:17 SamsungSans.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      5011099 2014-04-04 17:21 SamsungTTS.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1445519 2014-04-04 17:17 SamsungWidget_FavoriteApp.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        44728 2014-04-04 17:18 SamsungWidget_FavoriteApp.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root     21687924 2014-04-04 17:22 Samsungservice.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      5938447 2014-04-04 17:20 SecBrowser.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1666920 2014-04-04 17:19 SecBrowser.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1141259 2014-04-04 17:19 SecCalculator2.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       171744 2014-04-04 17:19 SecCalculator2.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      5001186 2014-04-04 17:17 SecCalendar.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      2478240 2014-04-04 17:19 SecCalendar.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1159009 2014-04-04 17:19 SecCalendarProviderM0.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       723232 2014-04-04 17:19 SecCalendarProviderM0.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root     14865691 2014-04-04 17:21 SecContacts.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      9356976 2014-04-04 17:20 SecContacts.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       126634 2014-04-04 17:19 SecContactsProvider.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      4664280 2014-04-04 17:19 SecContactsProvider.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       276076 2014-04-04 17:19 SecDownloadProvider.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       386840 2014-04-04 17:19 SecDownloadProvider.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       864151 2014-04-04 17:19 SecDownloadProviderUi.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       139928 2014-04-04 17:18 SecDownloadProviderUi.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root     17282463 2014-04-04 17:20 SecEmail_J.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root     10211160 2014-04-04 17:20 SecEmail_J.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       176448 2014-04-04 17:19 SecExchange.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      4252216 2014-04-04 17:19 SecExchange.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        46305 2014-04-04 17:18 SecFactoryPhoneTest.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root     19124515 2014-04-04 17:21 SecGallery2013.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      9549328 2014-04-04 17:21 SecGallery2013.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root         8026 2014-04-04 17:18 SecHTMLViewer.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root         7680 2014-04-04 17:18 SecHTMLViewer.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      2873645 2014-04-04 17:19 SecLauncher2.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      2027312 2014-04-04 17:19 SecLauncher2.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       172072 2014-04-04 17:18 SecLiveWallpapersPicker.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        29240 2014-04-04 17:18 SecLiveWallpapersPicker.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        25461 2014-04-04 17:18 SecMediaProvider.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       639304 2014-04-04 17:19 SecMediaProvider.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      8514038 2014-04-04 17:18 SecMms.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      4342112 2014-04-04 17:18 SecMms.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1350757 2014-04-04 17:18 SecNoteMyFiles.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       763472 2014-04-04 17:19 SecNoteMyFiles.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       174721 2014-04-04 17:19 SecOmaDownloadProvider.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       191480 2014-04-04 17:19 SecOmaDownloadProvider.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root     17438983 2014-04-04 17:21 SecPhone.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      3420632 2014-04-04 17:20 SecPhone.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root     49074496 2014-04-04 17:22 SecSettings.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      4246032 2014-04-04 17:20 SecSettings.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        61148 2014-04-04 17:18 SecSettingsProvider.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       125288 2014-04-04 17:19 SecSettingsProvider.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      4291973 2014-04-04 17:20 SecSetupWizard2013.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       138232 2014-04-04 17:19 SecSetupWizard2013.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root         6044 2014-04-04 17:18 SecTelephonyProvider.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       244872 2014-04-04 17:19 SecTelephonyProvider.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1201170 2008-08-01 22:00 SecVideoList.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       594624 2008-08-01 22:00 SecVideoList.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      5185280 2014-04-04 17:20 SecVideoPlayer.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1495824 2014-04-04 17:19 SecVideoPlayer.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root     11885298 2014-04-04 17:21 SecWallpaperChooser.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        58568 2014-04-04 17:19 SecWallpaperChooser.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        37508 2014-04-04 17:18 SecurityProviderSEC.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root         9104 2014-04-04 17:18 SecurityProviderSEC.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       818423 2014-04-04 17:18 SelfTestMode.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1097473 2014-04-04 17:19 SetupWizard.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       343906 2014-04-04 17:19 ShareShotService.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       294176 2014-04-04 17:18 ShareShotService.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root         2698 2014-04-04 17:18 SharedStorageBackup.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root         9608 2014-04-04 17:18 SharedStorageBackup.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root         7364 2008-08-01 22:00 Shell.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        19320 2008-08-01 22:00 Shell.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root         3838 2008-08-01 22:00 SimServicePermission.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      2004731 2014-04-04 17:19 SimpleAlarmClock.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        46216 2014-04-04 17:18 SimpleAlarmClock.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       803167 2014-04-04 17:17 SimpleFavoritesWidget.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        57480 2014-04-04 17:18 SimpleFavoritesWidget.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       255091 2008-08-01 22:00 SmartcardManager.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root         4076 2014-04-04 17:18 SmartcardService.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       162752 2014-04-04 17:19 SmartcardService.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        75070 2014-04-04 17:18 Stk.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        67688 2014-04-04 17:18 Stk.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       264451 2013-02-25 11:49 Street.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1578666 2014-04-04 17:19 SyncmlDM.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1131800 2014-04-04 17:19 SyncmlDM.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       193890 2014-04-04 17:19 SyncmlDS.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       603640 2014-04-04 17:18 SyncmlDS.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       102011 2014-04-04 17:18 SysScope.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      3884666 2014-04-04 17:20 SystemUI.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1188464 2014-04-04 17:19 SystemUI.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       329186 2014-04-04 17:18 TMServerApp.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       786128 2014-04-04 17:18 TMServerApp.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        62821 2014-04-04 17:18 Tag.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       312408 2014-04-04 17:18 Tag.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        12925 2008-08-01 22:00 TasksProvider.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       382120 2008-08-01 22:00 TasksProvider.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       882665 2014-04-04 17:19 TopicWall.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       194224 2014-04-04 17:18 TopicWall.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       779496 2014-04-04 17:19 TrimApp_phone_J.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        70146 2008-08-01 22:00 UltraCfg.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       113336 2008-08-01 22:00 UltraCfg.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root         3565 2014-04-04 17:18 UserDictionaryProvider.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        16064 2014-04-04 17:18 UserDictionaryProvider.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root     10851103 2014-04-04 17:21 Velvet.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root     10366437 2014-04-04 17:21 VideoHub.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      2946222 2014-04-04 17:20 Videos.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      3341582 2014-04-04 17:17 VoiceRecorder.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       678752 2014-04-04 17:19 VoiceRecorder.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root         4516 2014-04-04 17:18 VoiceSearchStub.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        42548 2014-04-04 17:18 VpnDialogs.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        21088 2014-04-04 17:18 VpnDialogs.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      6041322 2014-04-04 17:18 WeatherWall.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       105360 2014-04-04 17:18 WeatherWall.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        24199 2014-04-04 17:18 WebManual.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root         9144 2014-04-04 17:18 WebManual.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       234789 2014-04-04 17:19 WfdBroker.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        28072 2014-04-04 17:18 WfdBroker.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root        19492 2014-04-04 17:18 WlanTest.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        59768 2014-04-04 17:18 WlanTest.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       228953 2014-04-04 17:18 YahoonewsDaemon.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       150976 2014-04-04 17:18 YahoonewsDaemon.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       642168 2014-04-04 17:17 YahoonewsWidget.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       316648 2014-04-04 17:18 YahoonewsWidget.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       267733 2014-04-04 17:18 YahoostockDaemon.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       208136 2014-04-04 17:18 YahoostockDaemon.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root       951854 2014-04-04 17:18 YahoostockWidget.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root       766864 2014-04-04 17:18 YahoostockWidget.odex
-rw-r--r-- root     root      6789186 2014-04-04 17:19 YouTube.apk
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2014-04-04 17:22 mcRegistry
-rw-r--r-- root     root        29722 2014-04-04 17:18 minimode-res.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root      3772403 2014-04-04 17:21 sCloudBackupApp.apk
-rw-r--r-- root     root        63974 2014-04-04 17:18 sCloudBackupProvider.apk
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this: `adb shell ps | grep u0_`

If you want the count, add `wc` at the end: `adb shell ps | grep u0_ | wc -l`

The result:

[image: ](![http://i.imgur.com/L37yn3k.png])

Comment: I dont think this will show both the /system/app and /data/app running, does it?

Comment: @user2511126 the command `adb shell ps | grep u0_` will show all your apps that are currently running...irrespective of where they are installed. please give it a try, update your question with results, or any new issues.

Comment: @ashoke How can I filter that result in order to retrieve only the package names?